# How can I better manage using GSAP animations in Nuxt.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, gsap, es6-modules, nuxt.js

I am building a portfolio page using nuxt.js and Green Sock(GSAP) animation for on-load, menu, and page transitions. It is more difficult to accommodate GSAP than using CSS based transitions but I feel the results are worth it.

**I am not using webpack and nuxt correctly to make everything more modular and concise.** I need some help to better export variables and functions, use Vue.js reactive properties better, and take advantage of what's already available instead of working against it.

**My default.vue file has a method that manages the menu:**

```
showMenu() {
  if (process.browser) {
    var tl = new TimelineMax();

    var slide = document.querySelector("#slide-menu");
    var pl = document.querySelector("body");
    var nl = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");

    if (this.$store.state.menuIsActive === false) {
      tl
        .to(slide, 0.5, {
          y: "100%",
          ease: this.$store.state.animParams.ease
        })
        .staggerTo(
          nl,
          this.$store.state.animParams.dur3,
          {
            y: "-10px",
            autoAlpha: 1,
            ease: this.$store.state.animParams.ease
          },
          this.$store.state.animParams.dur2
        );
    } else if (this.$store.state.menuIsActive === true) {
      console.log("true");
      tl
        .staggerTo(
          nl,
          this.$store.state.animParams.dur3,
          {
            y: "10px",
            autoAlpha: 0,
            ease: this.$store.state.animParams.ease
          },
          this.$store.state.animParams.dur2
        )
        .to(slide, 0.5, {
          y: "-100%",
          ease: this.$store.state.animParams.ease
        });
    }
    this.$store.commit("toggleMenuState");
  }
}
```

**I have a menu.js middleware that closes the menu when open.** I would prefer to use the same variable but redeclare it instead:

```
import TweenMax from 'gsap'
export default function ({ store }) {
  if (store.state.menuIsActive === !false) {
    if (process.browser) {
      var tl = new TimelineMax()

      var slide = document.querySelector('#slide-menu')
      var nl = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link')

      if (store.state.menuIsActive === true) {
        console.log('initmenu')
        tl
          .staggerTo(
            nl,
            store.state.animParams.dur3,
            { y: '10px', autoAlpha: 0, ease: store.state.animParams.ease },
            store.state.animParams.dur2
          )
          .to(slide, 0.5, { y: '-100%', ease: store.state.animParams.ease })
        store.commit('setMenuState', false)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I duplicated the page transition because I couldn't get it working correctly in my nuxt.config.js. I would like to keep all of my transitions there or in a separate plugins file maybe but am not sure the best way to do so.

**From my root index.vue page file:**

```
import TweenMax from "gsap";
export default {
  transition: {
    name: "page",
    mode: "out-in",
    css: false,

    enter: function(el, done) {
      console.log("animenter contact");
      if (process.browser) {
        var tl = new TimelineMax();
        var tg = document.querySelectorAll(".el");
        var st = document.querySelector(".overlay-grid img");
        var box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
        tl.fromTo(st, 0.3, { x: -100 }, { x: 0, autoAlpha: 1 });
        tl.staggerTo(tg, 0.3, { autoAlpha: 1 }, 0.1);
        tl.staggerTo(box, 0.3, { autoAlpha: 1, onComplete: done }, 0.1);
      }
    },
    leave: function(el, done) {
      console.log("leaving contact...");
      if (process.browser) {
        var tl = new TimelineMax();
        var tg = document.querySelectorAll(".el");
        var st = document.querySelector(".overlay-grid img");
        var pl = document.querySelector("body");
        var box = document.querySelectorAll(".box");
        tl.fromTo(st, 0.3, { x: 0 }, { x: -100, autoAlpha: 0 });

        tl.staggerTo(tg, 0.3, { autoAlpha: 0 }, 0.1);

        tl.staggerTo(box, 0.3, { autoAlpha: 0, onComplete: done }, 0.1);
      }
    }
  }
```

**And finally, in nuxt.config.js:**

```
  router: {
    middleware: 'menu'
  },
build: {

    vendor: [
      'gsap',
....
    ] /*
  }
```

I also have some variables set in the store to manage state, and some transition durations so I don't have to edit them in as many places to see how something looks. It is becoming a lot of work to preview ideas or small changes and I wasn't able to find an in-depth article that tackles this problem.

Any help with tips and tricks for Nuxt, Vue, GSAP, Webpack, and Javascript in general would be greatly appreciated.